# After installing Adobe Acrobat, can I revert to Preview for handling PDF from Firefox?

Tags: preview, firefox, pdf

I was used to download PDF from Firefox and open them with Preview PDF.

Yesterday I installed Adobe Reader and now each time I click on a PDF link Firefox tries to open the PDF with Abode Reader. And it doesn't work even. See the picture below.

[image]

How can I go back to the previous behavior?

Comment: Does it add any add ons? If yes, delete them. By the way, why in the name of God did you install Adobe Reader?!

Comment: @duci9y ahaha you are right! Did it because it was suggested by a website for reading one of their document that cannot be viewed correctly with preview...

Comment: @duci9y No plugins and neither add-ons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1st thing to try

1. Open Firefox
2. Open Preferences (Firefox > Preferences, or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)
3. Select the Applications tab
4. Search for "pdf"
5. Change action to something else, then change it back to "Always Ask"
   [image: visual help]

## Verify this is set correctly

1. Open Finder
2. Search for .pdf
3. Right (<kbd>Option</kbd>) Click the first PDF that appears.
4. Click **Get Info**
5. Expand **Open With** (if it isn't already)
6. Change it to "Preview"
7. Click **Change All** button below the drop down menu
8. Accept the prompt.

For a visual representation:
[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]

Comment: It is already set in this way. That doesn't fix the problem. It's firefox that tries to use Adobe Reader.

Comment: Check Firefox Settings > Applications then. See if PDF is in that list.

Comment: That made the trick. I already checked it and it was already setted to "Always ask". Now I changed it and re-changed again and it fixed the problem. Can you update your answer please?